# plot these points xy in c3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I'm trying to generate a "scatter plot" chart in c3.js. My problem occurs when I want to plot these points. in c3.js the points do not match the real points in the plane.

[image]

what am I doing wrong?.

these are the points:

```
//x
['data1', 1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1],
//y
['data2', 2,3,4,7,8,9,8,7,3]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qrqquhvd/

```
  var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
      xs: {
        data1: "data2"
      },
      columns: [
        ['data1', 1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1],
        ['data2', 2,3,4,7,8,9,8,7,3]
      ],
      type: 'scatter'
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your (X,Y) coordinates mixed up, look at the c3 plot vs your real plot.  On the real plot your first point is (1,2) but on your c3 plot you have it as (2,1).

Either swap the values of data1 and data2 like so...

```
columns: [
  ['data1', 2,3,4,7,8,9,8,7,3],
  ['data2', 1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
],
```

Or change the xs to

```
xs: {
  data2: "data1"
},
```

Comment: I thank you very much for your time. But it does not work either. the graph is still the same.

Comment: @yavg Make sure you do either the first suggestion or the second, but not both... Take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/8bccg0nh/ I just swapped the data1 and data2 values and it works correctly.

Comment: what is the xs attribute used for?

Comment: "Specify the keys of the x values for each data." - http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-xs, so you're saying the you have the data1 values and data2 values, and it works like `xs: { y_values: x_values }`.  Alternatively, you can explicitly define the points that are x and y like this https://jsfiddle.net/xks5dfag/

Comment: Thank you! can you help me whit thits? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325699/my-chart-lines-are-not-in-order