# My chart lines are not in order

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have a graph and the result of joining all the lines should be as in the image. but currently they are not. what am I doing wrong?

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/r2uaq27a/

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    xs: {
      data1: "data2"
    },
    columns: [
      ['data1', 2,3,4,7,8,9,8,7,3],
      ['data2', 1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
    ]

  }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is possible with c3?  From what the documentation says, it leads me to believe that it isn't.  It automatically reorders your points, sorted by the x values in the (x,y) pair.

Comment: @kyle I do not know. I would expect that to be possible.

Comment: @kyle  do you know the answer to my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46334644/add-a-data-to-my-chart-in-c3-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [some what](https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/525) undocumented `xSort` property of `data` to `false`:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        xSort: false,
        x: 'x',
        order: function (i) { console.log(i); },
        columns: [
            ['x', 1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1],
            ['data1', 2,3,4,7,8,9,8,7,3]
        ]
    }
});
```

Running:

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    xs: {
      data1: "data2",
      data3: "data4"
    },
    xSort: false,
    columns: [
      ['data1', 2,3,4,7,8,9,8,7,3],
      ['data2', 1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1],
      ['data3', Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10],
      ['data4', Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10]
    ]

  }
});
```

```css
#catImage {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link data-require="c3.js@0.4.11" data-semver="0.4.11" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.css" />
<script data-require="c3.js@0.4.11" data-semver="0.4.11" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.js"></script>
<script data-require="d3@3.5.17" data-semver="3.5.17" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: this is incredible! I can not believe you could do it. I'm very impressed!. thank you very much. I only have one last question and I hope you can help me, I get confused a bit. How can I add another line with other points, and certain color and name ?. From already thank you very much!

Comment: @yavg, see updated code snippet for multi line support.

Comment: thank you very much. the only bad thing is not to evenly distribute the x-axis values. it looks bad. you are a genious! thank you very much!

Comment: can you help me with that ?  I would be even more grateful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46328589/present-in-a-more-pleasant-way-the-values-of-the-axis

Comment: Your intelligence surprises me too much! I'm really surprised. I wanted to ask you, there is a way to show the complete axes, so when you have negative values in x and y. For example https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-4f2307394c4f22261f62696c968730d6

Comment: @yavg, `c3.js` does not provide that level of customization.  But if you want a **hack**, [here you go](https://jsfiddle.net/9zmbq0g0/1/).  You might want to think about learning straight `d3.js` for the customization you need.

Comment: you are the best!!

Comment: can you help me please with this ?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345556/generate-point-to-point-animation-in-c3-js