# present in a more pleasant way the values of the axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

In my current chart the x-axis values are illegible. how can I improve the presentation or at least that the intervals of the x values have a uniform separation.

[image]

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    xs: {
      data1: "data2",
      data3: "data4"
    },
    xSort: false,
    columns: [
      ['data1', -4,3,4,7,8,9,8,7,3],
      ['data2', -5,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1],
      ['data3', Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10],
      ['data4', Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10]
    ]

  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9zmbq0g0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [axis.x.tick.values](http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-tick-values):

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    xs: {
      data1: "data2",
      data3: "data4"
    },
    xSort: false,
    columns: [
      ['data1', 2,3,4,7,8,9,8,7,3],
      ['data2', 1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1],
      ['data3', Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10],
      ['data4', Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10,Math.random() * 10]
    ]
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      tick: {
        values: d3.range(-5,10)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#catImage {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link data-require="c3.js@0.4.11" data-semver="0.4.11" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.css" />
<script data-require="c3.js@0.4.11" data-semver="0.4.11" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.js"></script>
<script data-require="d3@3.5.17" data-semver="3.5.17" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```