# add data to chart using c3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have a chart, in which I would like to add more data without replacing the data I have, either with a .push or adding a set of data without losing the ones I previously have.

How can I do it?

```
columns: [
      ['data1', -4,3,4,7,8,9,8,7,3],
      ['data1_x', -5,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1],
```

. 
.
.

```
//I need add the new data withouth remove the previous data

chart.load({
    xs: {
        data1: 'data1_x'
    },
    columns: [
        ["data1_x", 3,6],
        ["data1", 5,8]
    ]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aL8xhgpn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the data into an array

```
var data1 = ['data1',-4,3,4,7,8,9,8,7,3];
var data1_x = ['data1_x', -5,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1];
```

and push data into it.

Working sample below.

```js
var data1 = ['data1', -4, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 3];
var data1_x = ['data1_x', -5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    xs: {
      data1: "data1_x",
      data2: "data2_x"
    },
    xSort: false,
    columns: [
      data1,
      data1_x, ['data2', Math.random() * 10, Math.random() * 10, Math.random() * 10, Math.random() * 10, Math.random() * 10, Math.random() * 10],
      ['data2_x', Math.random() * 10, Math.random() * 10, Math.random() * 10, Math.random() * 10, Math.random() * 10, Math.random() * 10]
    ]

  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      tick: {
        values: d3.range(-5, 10)
      }
    }
  }
});

chart.internal.xAxis.g.attr('transform', "translate(0," + chart.internal.y(0) + ")");
chart.internal.yAxis.g.attr('transform', "translate(" + chart.internal.x(0) + ", 0)");
data1.push(5)
data1.push(8)
data1_x.push(3)
data1_x.push(6)


setTimeout(load, 5000);

function load() {
  chart.load({
    xs: {
      data1: 'data1_x'
    },
    columns: [
      data1_x,
      data1
    ]
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.18/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.18/c3.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Wow! Your intelligence surprises me. Just a detail and I hope you can help me. How can I generate an animation when a new point is added (without restarting all the points in the chart). this change looks very abrupt.

Comment: updated the code in my answer used timeout it will update after 5 secs., with animation

Comment: thank you very much friend!. It shows that you know a lot. I had done the settimeout, but what I mean is that properly there is no animation when you add a point. I would like to see an animation generated with the points that are added, point to point. something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/ej0wLtv6/

Comment: I think best would be to ask another question on SO.
If you feel i have answered your initial question kindly mark it as answered.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot. I hope you can help me with the other question.

Comment: Frankly, I have no idea how to get around that...apologies.