# generate point-to-point animation in c3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

How can I generate an animation when a new point is added (without restarting all the points in the chart). when a new point is added, the change is somewhat abrupt. the idea is to generate an animation when you add new or new points.

for example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ej0wLtv6/

this is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/pL4mL2sr/

```
setTimeout(load, 1000);
function load(){
    chart.load({
       xs: {
          data1: 'data1_x'
       },
       columns: [
          data1_x,
          data1
        ]
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[You want to apply a duration to the transition](http://c3js.org/samples/transition_duration.html):

By adding this onto your options that you pass to c3, it gives a smooth feel when points update

```
transition: {
  duration: 2000
}
```

Checkout out the updated fiddle for an example with your data: https://jsfiddle.net/j1afur1j/

Comment: I appreciate your effort as always, but there is only one animation with opacity, not point to point :(